# Setting a project level django constant

Tags: django

In my application, I set one configuration in my database (lets say `buffer_radius`) that is not going to change very frequently. I want to set one constant `BUFFER_RADIUS` in Django so that every-time Django restarted/redeployed, the value of this constant set to `buffer_radius`. I want to do this to minimize database call.

Comment: I remember doing this in rails initializer files but not sure where and how to do this in django.

Answer (score 0):

Put it the settings.py and you can use [Django-constance](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance) if you want your admins to change the value from Django Admin.

Comment: Can we import Django models in settings.py?

Comment: You shall put the value in the settings and not in the database.

Comment: The problem with putting the value in the settings is: everytime I wanted to change the value, I need to change my code. Keeping this on database, only a redeployment is enough.

Comment: Django-constance can help you in that.